# Dynamics 365 Schedule Board - can Dynamics 365 reference Data from a DB2 Database

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I have a short question - I want to use Dynamics 365 feature of Schedule Board for ressources.
My idea is, to connect the Dynamics 365 with a DB2 Database via ODBC to get the Appointments in the ScheduleBoard and with Dynamics 365 connect the Appointments with the Ressources.

This is just a quick question if it is possible to connect Dynamics 365 with a external ODBC Database via a Connector like PowerBI has - would this be possible or not, or has onyone tried a similar connection with ODBC to Dynamics 365?
My main Data is stored in a DB2 Database.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think this is possible in the direct way you have in mind but it should be possible by integrating your DB2 database into Dataverse or as a [Virtual Entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/customize/create-edit-virtual-entities?view=op-9-1) depending on your Dynamics 365 being a cloud or on-premise instance.